# Run a python module from an installed package

Tags: python, python-packaging, python-poetry

I have the following sample python application:

```
- testapp
-- __init__.py
-- main.py
-- hello
---- __init.py
---- hello.py
-- world
---- __init__.py
---- world.py
```

**main.py**

```
from testapp.hello import hello
from testapp.world import world

if __name__ == "__main__":
    hello.say()
    world.say()
```

**world.py**

```
def say():
    print('world')
```

**hello.py**

```
def say():
    print('hello')
```

then, I can go into testapp folder and run `python -m main`
I get the print of 'Hello world'

Fine, but what I would like to do is to build a package with this and install the package elsewhere to execute it.
I'm using poetry to build the `whl` package.
My question is, how to install the package somewhere else (on a server i.e.) and run it?
I would like to setup a distribution flow, where packages are build and stored on a private pypi repo, and servers can update and run the whole app.

I tried to make a poetry add on a folder on the server, it is working as the package is now installed but I  don't know how to launch the main module inside the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

super easy in fact..
after the package installation,

`python -m testapp.main`

that's it